# owl api non-buffering reasoner still needs a flush

Tags: owl, semantic-web, owl-api

I am using OWL API, and created a non-buffering reasoner in hope that so I would not need to make a call to `flush()`, all the time (i.e. the reasoner is always synchronised).

```java
    @Test
    public void reasonerQueryTest() throws OWLOntologyCreationException {
        OWLOntologyManager owlManager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
        OWLOntology o = owlManager.createOntology();
        ReasonerFactory reasonerFactory = new ReasonerFactory();
        OWLReasoner reasoner = reasonerFactory.createNonBufferingReasoner(o);
        reasoner.precomputeInferences(InferenceType.CLASS_ASSERTIONS);
        OWLDataFactory factory = owlManager.getOWLDataFactory();
        OWLNamedIndividual a = owlManager.getOWLDataFactory().getOWLNamedIndividual(IRI.create(":a"));
        OWLClass b = owlManager.getOWLDataFactory().getOWLClass(IRI.create(":b"));
        OWLClassAssertionAxiom classAssertionAxiom = factory.getOWLClassAssertionAxiom(b,a);
        o.add(classAssertionAxiom);
        reasoner.flush(); //NEEDED TO GET DESIRED OUTPUT
        owlManager.addAxiom(o,classAssertionAxiom);
        System.out.println(reasoner.getInstances(b,false).getFlattened());
    }
```

In this particular example I am obtaining instances of a class. The desired output is `[<:a>]`. To get the desired output I need to make a call to the flush method. How is the flush method working here since the reasoner has no buffer ?

Thanks a lot !

Flush method needed. How is it working ? And how can I remove the need for using the flush() method.

Comment: The OWLAPI does nothing with the buffering/non buffering flags except passing them to the reasoner, so this looks like it might be a problem with the reasoner library. Adding an axiom causes an ontology change to be sent to all listeners (the reasoner is one such listener) and then the listener is responsible for doing something with it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I am using HermiT.
`
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.owlapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.semanticweb.hermit</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5.519</version>
        </dependency>
`

Will further investigate the issue. Tested also with openllet and it works.